# C++ logging class instance identifier

Tags: c++, c++11

In my project, some classes are instantiated more than once. Each class logs some events. The logging method is a generic one used all around the project and it uses the standard *cout*. The log message contains the time, name of the class, name of the method, a variable value, and a custom message.

The disadvantage is that the log is not instance specific. I do not know which instance of the class wrote the log.

Is there a nice way to solve this problem without adding additional static members as instance counters to the classes? I am using boost and C++11. Maybe boost has something that might help.

The only solution I can think of is to include the instance address (this) to the log.

Comment: As you said, "this" helps differentiate between the instances, but if you want to know exactly which instance does what (especially between different runs of the program), you'll have to name them somehow at creation time (-> more members).

Comment: So you want to distinguish between objects of the same class.  What is the distinguishing feature, and how come it's not a (non-static) member of the class ?

Comment: Would it help you to just print out the address of the instance? That way you can tell that two instances writing the same line are different.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to differentiate between different classes *somewhere*, these are a few options (all rely on some kind of ID):

1. Add some additional static variable.
   Not an option for you, but in my opinion, the best way to go if you aim for readability.
2. Use `this`, as you suggested:
   This obviously generates unique IDs, but they will tend to be unreadable and hard to distinguish with growing address lengths (as only one or two characters might differ in a lengthy address string). Also, the addresses are likely to change between every run of the application (especially when employing ASLR), so you won't be able to see which exact instance created which line of output (if that's required).
3. Use `this` and *hash the value*:

To be honest, I don't see much of a difference to 2), but it might trigger some further ideas. Some ugly hack could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstddef>

class Logger
{
public:
    static void log(void* ptr)
    {
        using hash_type = std::uintptr_t;
        std::cout << std::hash<hash_type>{}(reinterpret_cast<hash_type>(ptr))
            << " logged something..." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

You can also consider [specializing `std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash#Example) for your classes and use that in the logging output. This would remove the problem of changing addresses between different runs, if implemented properly.

4. Generate an ID during construction (e.g. by passing some identifier to the constructor):
   This is not really an option since you have no evidence or control that a unique ID is generated for each class - unless you use some kind of (abstract) factory with access to a private constructor or some kind of global registry (see below).
5. Use some helper utility where your logging classes are registered and unique IDs are generated (something like a registration class).
   For simple logging purposes, IMHO this is bloat and does not add any value compared to 1).

*Conclusion:*
I would go for option 1) if readability for humans is of concern and for 2) if you simply want some number to distinguish between log messages (e.g. for piping and filtering).

Answer (score 1):

You can quite *easily* generate IDs via CRTP adaptor like that (if you can modify your classes a bit)

```
template<typename T>
struct enable_id
{
    int id = global_id++;
private:
    static int global_id;
};

template<typename T>
int enable_id<T>::global_id = 0;

class foo : public enable_id<foo>
{
};

template<typename T>
void log(const T& t)
{
    // if is_base_of
    std::cout << t.id << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to fix the problom is to print the address to indicate which object it is.  As following:

```
cout<<static_cast<void*>(this)<<endl;
```

Or output some features.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a protected class member containing the time of instance's creation at the root of all my class hierarchies, at least at the debugging stage. Very helpful for multi-threaded applications also.

Convert this time to whatever you want - string, milliseconds, epoch time - and you have a unique id for each and every instance.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only a few instances of class going to be, I would suggest you introduce a string member and initialize it with a unique name during object creation. It will help you in logs reading. By default, it may be initialized with object's address.